# prove that the unit circle is isomorphic to the quotient group $\Bbb R/K$, where $K$ is a normal subgroup of $(\Bbb R, +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Prove that the circle group $(S,$x$)$

where $S=\{z∈ \Bbb C | |z|= 1\}$

is isomorphic to the quotient group $\Bbb R/K$ where $K$ is a normal subgroup of $(\Bbb R , +)$

I understand the basic definition of isomorphism and how to show it, but I have no idea how to begin to tackle this question. Any hints and help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: since $\mathbb R$ is commutative, any subgroup is normal; anyway, consider $K=\mathbb Z$

Comment: The question is ambiguously stated. It should run, “There is a subgroup $K\subset\Bbb R$ such that$S\cong\Bbb R/K$”.

Answer (score 2):

The subgroup is $K=2\pi \mathbb  Z$, and the quotient map sends $\theta\mapsto e^{i\theta}$. Consider this a hint.

Comment: $+1$; or $K=\mathbb Z$ and $\theta\mapsto e^{2\pi i \theta}$